# This code tells you the number of capital letters there are. How can I get the same function without a for loop?

Tags: python

```
name=str(input("enter the string:"))
count=0
for x in name:
  if x.isupper():
    count=count+1
print("The number of capital letters found in the string is:",count)
```

How can I rewrite this code without a for loop that gets the same function?

Comment: `sum([x.isupper() for x in string])`   <- still looping really

Comment: @Chris why the square brackets? `sum` can directly take the generator expression. No reason to create the list in memory.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have no idea! Good catch :)

Comment: Why do you not want to use a for-loop? What counts as a for-loop for your purposes?  Have you tried *anything at all*?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Answer (score 6):

Since this seems like a homework problem, it's probably not appropriate to just post an answer.  To give you some hints:

- you could re-write the `for` loop as a `while` loop that uses a counter
- you could re-write the `for` loop as a `while` loop that pops characters off of `name` one-at-a-time, and terminates when `name` is empty
- you could use a list comprehension with a filter to get just the upper-case characters, and report the length of the resulting string
- you could write a recursive function
- you could use `filter` the same way you would use a list comprehension
- you could use `sum`, as suggested in comments above
- you could use `functools.reduce` (or just `reduce` if you're using a geriatric python interpreter)
- if you're feeling really perverse, you could use regular expressions

Along with probably a dozen other ways that I'm not thinking of now...

Comment: `map` + `sum`! A dozen of ways for sure.